# How can I put a field or any variable as a sequence in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I want to generate sequence in my sale order as `a/b/c` where `a` is the sequence number of a many2one field,`b` is the current year and `c` is the customer reference. I've coded like this. But the values won't be getting (except the year) in it becuase the create fn or so i think

```
def create(self, vals):
    seq = str(self.projects_id.sequence)
    year = str(datetime.now().year-2000)
    ref = str(self.client_order_ref)
    if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
        vals['name'] = seq+'/'+year+'/'+ref
    return super(sale_order,self).create(vals)
```

any idea?

Comment: @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
            vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('modelname') or 'New'
        result = super(sale_orde,r self).create(vals)
        return result   then in xml add  <openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
     
  <record id="" model="ir.sequence">
  <field name="name"></field>
  <field name="prefix">/</field>
  <field name="code"></field>
  <field name="suffix"></field>
  <field name="padding"></field>
</record>
</data>
</openerp>

Comment: Use of project.sequence is not good idea! because it is not going to be Unique!

Answer (score 2):

This is cruel mistake my friend!!

you are writing code in CREATE method and you wont be getting any record/recordset in self,

so you are not able to access fields like,

> self.projects_id.sequence

all values are in vals dictionary.

```
def create(self, vals):
    project_id = vals.get('projects_id',False)
    project_obj = self.env['project.project']

    seq = str(project_obj.browse(project_id).sequence)
    year= str(datetime.now().year-2000)
    ref = vals.get('client_order_ref','')

    if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
        vals['name'] = seq+'/'+year+'/'+ref
    return super(sale_order,self).create(vals)
```

**** using project sequence is not good idea! cause they are not unique.you might get duplicate sequence sometimes.***

Comment: danx mahn! i've sorted it out.

Comment: you are welcome. and accept the answer if it helped you!